# want to delay closing of fancybox window

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to automatically close a fancybox iframe, but I want to give it a delay.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 parent.$.fancybox.close();
});
```

The code above will automatically close the window successfully, but I want to add a delay, so they may read the message the page displays before it auto closes for them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp):

```
setTimeout("parent.$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery 1.4 try the [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function:

parent.$.fancybox.**delay(2000).**close();